# Defining a new shortcut disables unexpectedly another shortcut

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, shortcuts

To prevent closing Firefox or an other application by mistake using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> I added a keyboard shortcut with this combination to xclock.

It works fine but unexpectedly the shortcut "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> ==> Select all" doesn't work any more system wide.

Comment: Check to be sure you didn't inadvertently disable or remove "ctrl+A" when you created the other. Check you keyboard shutcuts...

Comment: @George I did it thrice. When I delete the added shortcut Ctrl+Q, the "Select all" shortcut returns to normal !
Have you tried to produce it yourself?